# Cant install zimbra64 bit to ubuntu64bit

Tags: software-installation, zimbra

i'm trying to install [Zimbra][1] 64 bit on ubuntu 18.04 64 bit. Platforms are correct. But i always get this error. What is the issue?

> Server - VM on windows Server 2016 Hyperv with 8 GB RAM. Updated and
>   has internet connectivity. Errors are attached.

if i skip the check i get following error

> ERROR: Unable to install required packages 
>   Fix the issues with remote package installation and rerun the installer

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jry6c.png)

I only have one vm with ubuntu 18.04. Downloaded url is - 
https://files.zimbra.com/downloads/8.8.15_GA/zcs-8.8.15_GA_3869.UBUNTU18_64.20190918004220.tgz.

I also used freshly installed and updated Ubuntu .

I tried with CentOS too. Same result. Am I downloading the wrong version. Can u send me the correct link for CentOS 7?

Comment: Zimbra for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  64bit x86 (MD5) (SHA 256). I also tried the version  for u untu 16. Same result.

Comment: I only have one vm with ubuntu 18.04. Downloaded url is - https://files.zimbra.com/downloads/8.8.15_GA/zcs-8.8.15_GA_3869.UBUNTU18_64.20190918004220.tgz.

Comment: None of use can send you a correct installation link for CentOS. For that, please consult the support team at the software publisher.